# Auto Correcting Date Format STRING "dd/MM/yyyy"

Tags: vb.net, arrays, date-format, date-formatting, date

I am manipulating xml with lots of date of birth.  XMLs are already loaded onto datatable. The format we need is "dd/MM/yyyy" The dates are messy such as "dd-MM-yyyy" or "dd.MM.yyyy" so I am thinking to write a function that will auto correct on a set of predefined separators to a correct format. so I am thinking to do something like this _

but of course, this won't just work .. i cannot use replace to replace an array. If i can just do that, everything would be fine. Hope someone can point out a way around. Thankssssss so much Indeed.

```
Dim str As String = ""
Dim keywords() As String = {"-", "_", ".", "\"}

For Each x In dt.Rows
    str = x("DOB")
    If keywords.Contains(str) Then
        str = str.Replace(keywords, str)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it made .. Thanks all for the help .. hope it is useful for other as well ..

```
    Public Function arrayReplace(ByVal dt As DataTable) As DataTable

    Dim str As String = ""
    Dim sep As String() = {"-", "_", ".", "\", "'"}
    For Each x In dt.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To Old.Length - 1
            str = x("DOB").Replace(sep(i), "/")
            x("DOB") = str
        Next
    Next
    Return dt

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats why I used the culture, then my problem cleared..

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Threading

blah..blah..blah..

Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", False)
```

Comment: I can't see how this would help my problem sir

Comment: Laurence ...While you set the "en-GB" culture, automatically all of your dates will be in dd/MM/yyyy format...also you can revert back to en-US whenever its required..

Comment: Thanks for suggestion sir .. it's sensible indeed .. but as I said, I am to manipulate DOB in String format from XMLs which come from users which i need to convert a correct format .. which one of our softwares understands ... I don't think using that Globalization.Culture would help ..